# Fix Warning - key() expects para 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wordpress 4.9.8` and `PHP 7.1.8`.

I am using the following to get the `post-meta` from a post.

```
        $a = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cegg_data', true);
        $keys = key($a); //  here I get the warning
```

For some posts `$a` becomes an empty string. However, I only know this after I query `get_post_meta` hence the warning gets thrown.

> Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Any suggestions how to fix the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function returns a single value, if the third parameter is set to true (its default value is false)

```
get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

> `$single`
>       (bool) (Optional) Whether to return a single value.
>       Default value: false
>
> **Return** (mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of meta data field if $single is true.

Now, you are using  `$a = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cegg_data', true);` . Clearly, the third parameter is true, hence it returns a string, **not an array**

Now, the [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function is used to return the element key from the current internal pointer position. It expects an array as a parameter.

```
mixed key ( array $array )
```

Since you are passing a string to `key()` function, that is why you are getting the Warning.

Now, you could set the third argument in `get_post_meta(...)` call to false (or dont specify the third parameter so that it considers default value false), to get an array, like this:

```
$a = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cegg_data', false);
```